# How to convert string to have \n instead of line break

Tags: java, string, junit, newline

```
AssertThat( myString1 , is (myString2));
```

is getting failed.

So I checked two values through an eclipse debug "variables" console.

myString1

```
hello
my name is 
alex
```

myString2

```
hello\n my name is\n alex
```

If I try with String.compareTo, it failed.

My question is two,
1. Are those actually same? (console displays)?
2. If not, how do I convert from myString1 to myString2?

Comment: It seems there's an additional space between the first `\n` and `my` in `myString2`.

Comment: Thank you all for the tip. I was confused because when I check a log file, "myString1" simply turns out myString2 form. In order to solve my problem, I simply used escapeJava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this import-- org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(StringVariableNameHere);
```

Would serve as a hint to your question

Answer (score 0):

1) No, they are obviously not the same.

2) What about this:

```
myString2 = myString1.replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n");
```

or better:

```
myString2 = myString1.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator", "\\\\n");
```

There is no need to use external packages.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand here is: **we** can **not** tell you about **your requirements**.

It is really simple: two string objects are **only** equal, if `a.equals(b)` returns true. So, obviously, the two strings from your example are **not** equal.

But the questions behind that are: does it matter to your production code; and thus: how should your test code deal with it?!

Meaning: **you** as the owner of production and test code, **you** have to understand if you care about those newline characters. There could be plenty of options to address your failing test:

1. Why does the one string have \n chars in it; and the other has not? Is your `expected value` simply wrong?
2. Or is your expected value really "correct"; and thus: the production code is giving an **unexpected** result; thus indicating that there is a problem within your production code?

So, yes, the correct answer might be to massage that assert (or its expected value) to allow for such \n chars. But the correct answer could as well be "fix broken production code". As you are using assertThat, you might write your own matcher for strings that simply ignores \n chars somehow; and that would give "true" for your example strings ...

As said: there are several options to "fix" this; but **you** have to understand which one really fixes **your** problem.